# DigitalOcean and docker swarm between regions

Tags: docker, containers, cluster-computing, digital-ocean, docker-swarm

I'm building docker swarm cluster for my backend and wanna join nodes from different regions for example manager on NY1 and one node in London and another two in Singapore for better balancing and fast access, but the problem is - DigitalOcean don't provide private network between data centers   (only between droplets inside one region. So my question is it possible to connect droplets on different data centers by using maybe special network adapter?

Comment: Seems like a question for superuser or so.

Comment: It is not recommended to span a Swarm across regions. The network latency will give you poor performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the public IP to create the cluster. I don't think it will be possible to run 2 droplets from different regions on the same network.

**edit**

In the other case, you may simply move to other clouds provider (like aws) where VPC peering is available. There you will have the option to connect to multiple private networks span across regions using private IP.

Comment: Thank you, i get it yesterday. But next problem - is too slow (i mean communicate between nodes)

Comment: Then you may move to other clouds provider (like aws) where VPC peering is available. There you will have the option to connect to multiple private networks span across regions using private IP.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to do so using external IP, but it is no way recommended. Because there are communication ports which need to be exposed for the same.

Then securing those endpoint is an additional responsibility you have. Security will have two aspect, encrypted communication (using SSL client certs) and authentication/authorization (SourceIP based)

Network latency is another issue, so that is why this is no way a recommended thing to do